# Performance issues with JBoss 7.1.1 and ActiveMQ

Tags: jboss7.x, activemq-classic

1. We upgraded our application from “JBoss 5.1 with JBoss Messaging” to “JBoss 7.1.1 Final with ActiveMQ 5.8.0”. We were expecting performance improvement but we saw 20 to 30% of performance loss.
2. We are using JDBC persistence for ActiveMQ and our MDB’s do good amount of DB transactions which slows them down. But this set up is same for JBoss 5.1 and JBoss 7.1.1
3. When we configure Active MQ as JCA using activemq.rar we see around 50 % loss in performance.
4. When we configure Active MQ embedded we still see around 50 % loss in performance.
5. When we run ActiveMQ external as standalone the performance loss is around 15 to 20 %.
6. We have also tested ActiveMQ and JBoss 5.1 combination and we don’t see any performance loss.
7. We searched through forums and JBoss bug tracking system and we don’t see any issue of this type reported against JBoss 7.1.1 or fixed for JBoss 7.2

Are we missing something? We need to make this work with JBoss 7.1.1

Any pointers will be helpful

Thanks in Advance

Nitesh

Comment: What are you doing with ActiveMQ - queues/topics? What sort of throughput are you looking for? What does your physical setup look like - are ActiveMQ and JBoss on the same server/inside the same JVM? Is ActiveMQ using the same database as the rest of your application?

Comment: Thanks for reply. We are using ActiveMQ as a replacement for JBoss Messaging. We are using its persistence capabilities and load balancing in clustered environment. We are running ActiveMQ and JBoss inside same JVM. We also tried running ActiveMQ in different JVM but without much success. We don't see any problem with ActiveMQ because same configuration works with JBoss 5.x. It looks like JBoss 7 is slowing down under load or we are missing some configuration

Comment: Since you're using JDBC store for messages and running AMQ embedded inside JB7, are you hooking up the the JDBC persitence driver to distributed JTA transactions? Such a thing could steal some performance.

Comment: yes we are using JTA, but I have also tried disabling persistence and even replacing ActiveMQ with simple java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue but no success.

Comment: What sort of messages are you sending - ByteMessage/StringMessage/ObjectMessage? Are you sending over queues or topics?

Comment: If you get performance issues even with a LinkedBlockingQueue, doesn't this eliminate ActiveMQ as the source of the issue?  Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: Yes, it eliminates ActiveMQ and therefore we are also thinking that there is some problem with our setting up of JBoss 7. 
We are using queues and sending text messages. In are test two queues are involved and around 50000 messages are processed per in an hour. After receiving messages our consumers make some database transactions start new threads to do some tasks. These threads after doing its work post messages to same queues. These activities are taking some time and therefore our consumers are slow. But same code work faster is JBOSS 5 with JBoss Messaging.